# Pros and Cons with installing Kotlin standalone compiler instead of using IntelliJ Kotlin plugin?

Tags: kotlin, jvm

i understand that i can use Kotlin Plugin comes with IntelliJ but i can also install Kotlin standalone compiler. Is there any pros/cons using standalone vs IntelliJ own integrated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that:

1. Any real Kotlin project (including projects in IntelliJ) should use a build system such as [Gradle](https://www.gradle.org/) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/).
2. Enabling Kotlin support in a Gradle/Maven project will automatically download the correct compiler (and switch it when you update the Kotlin version in the config file) and not care about whether you have a stand-alone version installed.
3. Any other Kotlin tool will likely be integrated with them as well.

So the standalone compiler is pretty much only useful when you want to try something quickly outside any project, but then https://play.kotlinlang.org/ or https://try.kotlinlang.org/ can work as well; and again let you switch between Kotlin versions simpler than a manually installed compiler.

Running [Kotlin scripts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html#using-the-command-line-to-run-scripts) may be the only case where I would use the stand-alone compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Not much, but having own install have few advantages, but probably not needed by most people on their machines:

- You don't need intellij, so you can use that compiler in other IDE or just for other applications
- You can use different version of compiler than the one from plugin.

But in most cases integrated one is all you need.